# Climbing techique with panniers and cleats

Tags: technique, climbing, cleat

In the last year I started using cleats (2 bolts SPD) on my touring bike, which I often use with rear panniers on biking holiday (travelled about 2000 km with this set up).

The struggle I have is when cycling on a steep climb: in certain cases, when I am already using the shortest gears, I have to trade off between two opposite necessities:

- if I push harder without standing on the pedals I end up lifting my front wheel
- if I don't push harder I go too slow to keep a decent equilibrium

Until I used clip less pedals I could easily put my foot on the ground in case of necessity, but now the concern of having locked feet adds another source of uncertainty.

I have tried releasing one foot during the climb, but it goes without saying that pedaling gets way more clumsy.

**What is a good technique to climb steep road with cleats and back panniers?**

Comment: What cleat system are you using. MTBers using SPD's have this happening all the time, and (mostly :) ) unclip when needed.

Comment: @mattnz, added that info in the question

Comment: Do you also find that a precautionary unclip puts you in a weaker pedalling position? I do with SPDs on a tourer, so I prepare to bail if I stall, but that makes me stall. I haven't found releasing one foot helps (and in fact went over onto the still-clipped side on an uphill emergency stop recently).

Comment: @ChrisH, to be sure I don't clip it back while pedaling I have to keep the foot more to the forward than normal, which is not really good combined with the small surface of the cleat and the need to transfer force to the pedal.

Comment: That's the problem I have too -- I can pedal OK under the arch in my shoes for a bit, but not with full force or good geometry, and an intermediate position between clipped in and under the arch skids around

Comment: You'll have to practice unclipping until it's so deeply rooted that you can do it without thinking.Remaining clipped-in is way much safer as it seems because it improves the balance and the control of the bike and you can't slip from the pedal accidentally.

Comment: @Carel however instinctively you can unclip, when you stop pedalling on a 26% hill at about 5km/h you stop instantly. Then you have to get both feet out, wherever they are in the stroke, and on the ground. I happened to fall to the side with a stiff cleat, which was also at the top/back of the stroke when this happened to me the other day (that's where those numbers came from). If you can (i) trackstand, and (ii) get your feet down from a trackstand then all credit to you, otherwise there's some limit beyond which you need to move unrealistically fast

Comment: Try the same climb with empty panniers.  See how different it feels to you.

Comment: @L.Dutch Are you sitting or standing up?  If you are sitting, I suggest standing up, which will shift the weight on the bike forward and keep the front wheel on the ground.  The way I approach a hill is ready to shift into easier gears: attack the hill, while you have good momentum, shift into an easier gear (don't wait until your legs are tired or you are out of breath), then continue into easier gears as needed, lastly zig zag your way up the hill.  When you top the hill, shift into harder gears so that your heart rate doesn't sky rocket, and work your way back to a comfortable gear.

Comment: @L.Dutch If your knees hurt, check seat alignment at a bike shop; if your quads are burning, sit and zig zag.

Comment: @ChrisH when running out of speed, you countersteer to tilt the bike to which side feels better and before you stop and unclip that foot, not both. It may take some practice but is a useful skill.

Comment: @ojs I can ride arbitrarily slowly, so I understand about countersteering while moving, and in fact that's exact what I do. The problem comes when you don't know that you're going to fail to get your foot over top dead centre, and you lose the momentum you need to steer or control which way you tip. This is less likely when clipped in of course, but still happens

Comment: What grade of incline is this happening on? When I was on tour, any time I was on a steep enough uphill that the front wheel could have potentially been lifting, I was already long since standing and in my lowest gear. That being said, I was also using small front panniers which makes a big difference. Have you considered adding some of those, or even just a handlebar bag with 5-10 lbs in it to balance this up a bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that may help a lot is shifting some load weight forwards.  In other situations I've found that a surprisingly small amount of weight shifted from behind the back axle to the front forks improves handling a lot.  For example rather than mounting a D lock behind a child seat, I put it on the front forks. That's something like 1% of the total weight, or 4% of the non-rider weight.

This may lead to a bar bag, bar/fork-mounted bottle holders, or front panniers, though I'm trying to avoid the latter (as it seems are you).

Even loading differently within the panniers might make a difference.

Comment: This is very much a partial attempt to address the problem, but I felt ust too much for a comment

Comment: Rear weight that is behind the wheel/road contact patch is the same as negative weight, or lift on the front wheel.  Even moving a full waterbottle from the seat tube to the downtube can have an impact.  I'd suggest a handlebar bag, or front rack, or front panniers, or leave the rear panniers off and use a back pack to help get the weight forward on a climb.

Comment: @Criggie's right and of course *behind* changes with incline

Answer (score 4):

A good option, if you can't shift any packed weight to the front of the bike, is to lean forward over the handlebars while climbing. You'll distribute your weight more equally between the wheels and avoid lifting the front wheel. Be sure to have the bike in the lowest gear before you start the climb, and just spin all the way up the hill. You will move slower, but the bike will stay stable, and is actually a little more efficient in terms of energy expenditure.

This will require a stronger core, so if you find it difficult at first, add a couple sets of front and side ab crunches to your morning routine.

There may not be a perfect solution to this depending on how much rear weight you are carrying. If it's really a lot of weight, the only good solution may be front mounted carrying systems like panniers or a front basket/bag.